# what's difference between const auto and const type*

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, auto

why error happend, I think const auto data_0 should be the same with const Data* data_1,
what's the difference bwtween data_0 and data_1?

```
class Data {
public:
  Data(int val_) : val(val_) {
  }
  ~Data() {
  }
  void SetVal(int val_) {
    val = val_;
  }
private:
  int val;
};

Data* GetData(int val) {
  return new Data(val);
}

int main () {
  const auto data_0 = GetData(0);
  const Data* data_1 = GetData(0);
  data_0->SetVal(1);  // OK 
  data_1->SetVal(1);  // error: passing ‘const Data’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: `data_0`'s type is `Data* const data_0;`.

Answer (score 3):

`const` applies to the thing on its left, unless there is nothing then it applies to the thing on its right.

In `const auto data_0 = GetData(0);`, the `const` applies to whatever type `auto` deduces to, which in this case is `Data*`. So, the final declaration is:

`Data * const data_0 = GetData(0);`

The `const` applies to the pointer itself, not the thing it is pointing at. Thus, `data_0` is a const pointer to a non-const `Data` object. `SetVal()` is a non-const method, so it can be called on the object.

In `const Data* data_1 = GetData(0);`, the `const` applies to `Data`. So, the final declaration is:

`Data const * data_1 = GetData(0);`

The `const` applies to the thing being pointed at, not to the pointer itself. Thus, `data_1` is a non-const pointer to a const `Data` object. `SetVal()` is not a const method, so it cannot be called on the object.

Answer (score 1):

> what's difference between const auto and const type*

`const auto` will be deduced from the initialiser and will be a const qualified type. In case of `data_0`, the type of the initialiser is a pointer to non-const `Data` and therefore the deduced type becomes a const qualified pointer to non-const `Data` i.e. `Data* const`.

`const type*` is a non-const qualified pointer to a const qualified object of type `type`. The difference is that one is non-const pointer to const and the other is const pointer to non-const.

> why error happend

Because you call a non-const qualified member function through a pointer to const.

> I think const auto data_0 should be the same with const Data* data_1

It isn't, and it shouldn't be.